# Add second facet grid or second discrete y-axis label GGPlot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

Suppose I have this dataframe:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(magrittr)
library(tidyr)

df2 <- data.frame(tissue = c("Blood", "Nerve", "Stomach", "Liver", "Blood", "Kidney"),
                  qtl = c("e", "s", "e", "e", "s", "s"),
                  gene = c("gene1", "gene1", 
                           "gene2", "gene2",
                           "gene3", "gene4"),
                  value = c(0.4, 0.2, 0.1, 0.9, 0.5, 0.3),
                  second_label = c("label1", "label1", "label1","label1",
                                  "label2", "label2"))
```

And I plot it as such:

```
ggplot(df2, 
       aes(x=tissue, y=qtl,
           size=value))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_grid(rows = vars(gene),
             scales = "free", 
             space='free',
             switch = "y")+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=8,angle = 90, hjust=1, vjust=0.2),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=8),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(color = "black"),
        strip.text.y.left = element_text(size = 8, angle=0),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        panel.spacing.y = unit(0.5, "lines"),
        strip.placement = "outside",
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "#ededed", size = 0.5))
```

This code yields the plot below (see first image)

[image]

However, I want to add a second facet wrap, being the "loci" and place it on the right side of the figure.

[image]

Is this possible? I know in `facet_grid`, you can do it where one variable is the column and the other is the row, but I haven't seen how to do it where both are rows.

I've looked into adding a secondary y-axis with `sec.axis` but that seems to only be for continuous variables.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: OP, do you have an extended dataset that can be used to plot "loci2"?  If I understand correctly, you have 4 genes in loci1 and you'll have... let's say 4 *other* genes in loci2.  You want to plot them all as rows (vertically), and have rows 1-4 associated with "loci1" and rows 5-8 associated with "loci2".  Is that correct?

Comment: This is where it gets tricky. Loci1 should be for two genes (gene1 and gene2) but there are 4 rows for it with the "e" and "s" dimension. 

I essentially want loci1 to map to genes1 and 2 and loci2 to map to genes3 and 4. I can create an extended toy dataset if need be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly recommend the `ggh4x` package ([github link here](https://github.com/teunbrand/ggh4x)), which can handle this issue nicely via [nested facets](https://teunbrand.github.io/ggh4x/articles/Facets.html#extended-facets-1) via `facet_nested()`.  Here, you facet according to `df2$gene`, but indicate the nesting of those facets happens according to `df2$qtl`.

Here's an example of code that shows you some basic functionality applied to `df2`.  Note I changed some strip background formatting to make the faceting more clear.  There's a lot of other options that might work better for you in that package.

```
p <-
  ggplot(df2, aes(x=tissue, y=qtl, size=value))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_nested(qtl + gene ~ .) +
  
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=8,angle = 90, hjust=1, vjust=0.2),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=8),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(color = "black"),
        strip.text.y.left = element_text(size = 8, angle=0),
        strip.background = element_rect(fill='white', color="black"),
        panel.spacing.y = unit(0.5, "lines"),
        strip.placement = "outside",
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "#ededed", size = 0.5))
p
```

[image]

Comment: This looks helpful! What I'm looking to do though is facet by "gene" and "second_label". Where gene is on the left side and label is on the right. I'll try this package out!